# What resources are required to develop apps for the Google Chrome WebStore

Tags: google-chrome, webstore

Is there a separate plugin in eclipse i would be needing to develop apps for the Chrome WebStore? Precise what resources and tools do i need to develop apps specifically for the WebStore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no plugin in eclipse for Chrome extension/app development (you dont even need one actually). All you need is a Text-editor and Chrome.[This might help you get started.](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html)